# How to Maximize Screen from VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, maximize-window, wscript.shell

The web application that displays database information is much more readable in full-screen mode rather than a small window.  Problem is, I cannot get the window to maximize from UFT/QTP.

I've tried running the browser object from Wscript.Shell, but the application returns to UFT and maximizes that window instead of the newly created browser window.

```
siteA = "https://google.com"
Const max_window = 3
Set browobj = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'browobj.Run "chrome -k -incognito -url "&siteA
browobj.Run "chrome -incognito -url "&siteA, max_window
oShell.SendKeys "% x"
browobj.sendkeys "{F9}"
browobj.sendkeys "(% )X"
browobj.SendKeys "% x"

Set browobj = Nothing
```

Any solutions to maximizing the window with the focus object of the new browser?

**Edit:**

Even below will not maximize taken from this [List of Controls](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension) is not working.

```
SystemUtil.Run "chrome.exe" , siteA ,,,3 
chrome.exe  --incognito --start-maximized
```

If you shut down all instances of chrome these controls work fine, but if you have an active window in chrome it will take those properties.

Comment: Does [AppActivate](https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a function defined during our browser login process that grabs the window and maximises it so that our UFT processes run with a (nearly) full screen browser - we don't need to hide the menu bar etc.  This is the function we are using:

```
Public Function MISC_MaximiseBrowser(ByVal oBrowser, ByRef ErrorMsg)
    LOG_Write vbNewLine & "MISC_MaximiseBrowser"
    LOG_Write "oBrowser: " & oBrowser.GetROProperty("TestObjectName")

    Dim Hwnd
    dim bIsMax, bIsMaxable

    MISC_MaximiseBrowser = True

    Hwnd = oBrowser.Object.HWND

    If Window("hwnd:=" & Hwnd).GetROProperty("maximized") Then
        bIsMax = True
    Else
        bIsMax = False
    End If

    If Window("hwnd:=" & Hwnd).GetROProperty("maximizable") Then
      bIsMaxable = True
    Else
      bIsMaxable = False
    End If

    If Not bIsMax And bIsMaxable Then
        Window("hwnd:=" & Hwnd).Maximize
    End If

End Function
```

What this does is accepts the `Browser` UFT object you're working with and grabs the handle for it.  If the browser is not already maximized and it's possible to maximize it, it will do so.

You can ignore the `LOG_Write` statements at the start of the function - those are for our internal logging steps